# Firefox, ie7, and ie6 are not working with this java script

Tags: javascript, css

With the java script below, firefox, ie7, and ie6 are not working properly (ie8 worked after 
applied getElementsByClassName.polyfill.js.) Can anyone find any problem on the script below for 
firefox, ie7, and ie6 to work? (Chrome and safari worked fine before applied the polyfill.js .)

This java script is designed to open and close the several levels of categories by clicking.

```
/*------------------------------------------
Open or close the specified node.
------------------------------------------*/
function openOrClose(tgt){

//To make the list visible when the specified node is hidden.
if(tgt.style.visibility == "hidden"){
    tgt.style.display = "block";
    tgt.style.visibility = "visible";

    tgt.style.height = "auto";
    tgt.style.paddingTop = "0.25em";
    tgt.style.lineHeight = "1em";
    tgt.style.opacity = 1.0;

}
//To make the list hide when the specified node is not hidden.
else{
    tgt.style.display = "none";

    tgt.style.visibility = "hidden";
    tgt.style.height = "0px";
    tgt.style.paddingTop = "0";
    tgt.style.lineHeight = 0;

    tgt.style.opacity = 0;
   }
   }

   /*------------------------------------------
   To open the list
   ------------------------------------------*/
   function listopen(lv, num){
   var tgt = document.getElementsByClassName("level" + lv)[num];

    //To search the next level -> to open the next level list.
   for(var i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("level" + (lv+1)).length; i++){
    var next_tgt = document.getElementsByClassName("level" + (lv+1))[i];
    //li

    if (next_tgt.parentNode == tgt || next_tgt.parentNode.parentNode == tgt){
        openOrClose(next_tgt);
    }
    }
    //To search the next level -> change the shape of the button that is displayed.
    for(var i=0; i < tgt.childNodes.length; i++){
    var next_tgt = tgt.childNodes[i];
    //ul
    if(next_tgt.tagName == "UL"){
        if(next_tgt.style.height == "0px"){
            if(event.srcElement.parentNode.className == "category_header plus"){
                event.srcElement.innerText = '?';
                event.srcElement.parentNode.className = "category_header minus";
            }
            next_tgt.style.height = "auto";
        }
        else{
            for(var i=0; i<next_tgt.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++){
                if(event.srcElement.parentNode.className == "category_header minus"){
                    event.srcElement.innerText = '＋';
                    event.srcElement.parentNode.className = "category_header plus";
                }
            }
            next_tgt.style.height = "0px";
        }
        }
        }
       }

     /*------------------------------------------
     To set up the click event
     ------------------------------------------*/
      function setclickevent(tgt, lv, num){
       //To make invisible when the level is other than 1.
      if(lv!=1){
    tgt.style.visibility = "hidden";
    tgt.style.display = "none";
    tgt.style.height = "0px";
    tgt.style.lineHeight = 0;
    tgt.style.paddingTop = 0;
    tgt.style.paddingBottom = 0;
    if(tgt.parentNode.tagName == "UL"){
        tgt.parentNode.style.height = "0px";
        tgt.parentNode.style.margin = "0";
        tgt.parentNode.style.padding = "0";
        tgt.parentNode.style.border = "none";
        }
        }
        var hasLink_flg;
         if(tgt.childNodes.length){
    for (var j = 0; j < tgt.childNodes.length; j++) {
        //To enlarge the scope where you can click.
        if(tgt.childNodes[j].tagName == 'A'){
            tgt.setAttribute('onclick', 'location.href="' +  
     tgt.childNodes[j].getAttribute('href') + '"');
        }
        //To add the event function of the accordion list
        else if(tgt.childNodes[j].tagName == 'UL'){
            //To display ? and add the list open function.
            var linkObj = document.createElement("a");
            linkObj.innerText = '＋';
            tgt.childNodes[0].className="category_header plus";
            tgt.childNodes[0].appendChild(linkObj);
            j++;
            linkObj.parentNode.setAttribute('onclick', 'listopen(' + lv + ',' + num + ')');

            //tgt.setAttribute('onclick', 'listopen(' + lv + ',' + num + ')');
            break;
          }
         }
         }
        }

       /*------------------------------------------
       Initialization 
        ------------------------------------------*/
      // To search all the node that has level? class and initiali
      function initCategoryList(){
      var lv = 0;
        //To add the click event to all the node that has level?
         while(document.getElementsByClassName("level" + (++lv)).length){
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("level" + lv).length; i++) {
        setclickevent(document.getElementsByClassName("level" + lv)[i], lv, i);
             }
           }
         }
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console (Firebug, etc)?

Comment: people still support IE6???

Comment: There are several css errors and I can not tell how important they are, and one reference error "event is not defined " from java script itself.

Answer (score 0):

As I know,
tgt.style.display = "none";  //is fine with IE6,7,8,9,10,ff,CHORME
But,
tgt.style.opacity = 0;   //is not coperate with IE8.

I suggest you to apply jQuery and write jQuery sentence to avoid browser differences.

like:     $(tgt).hide
or:       $(tgt).css({ display: "none", height: "0px" });

Comment: How hard or time-consuming is it going to be to convert from java script to jQuery? Are there any converter for a situation like this? Great suggestions, and appreciated.

Comment: If you applied jQuery.js to the <head>,you can write the jQuery sentence anywhere in your <script> file as long as you follow the grammar.Read a manual and convert from java script to jQuery anytime. http://jquery.com/

Comment: To meeming, Thanks a lot for your advice, and I will try it since you made me feel that it won't be as hard as I first thought. ???